# Java interfaces and problems with information output to the console

Tags: java, interface, tostring, implementation

Initially, my piece of code looked like this :

```
public interface Picture {
    public String toString();
}

class PolyLine extends Line implements Picture{
    int numSides =0;
    Line sideLengths[];
    public PolyLine(Line[] l1) {
        super(l1);
        sideLengths = l1;
        numSides = l1.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        
        return " "+"number of sides "+ numSides + " "+ "coordinates of the beginning and end of the lines that make up the polygon\n"+ Arrays.toString(sideLengths) + " "  ;
    }
}
```

And everything worked great.But since I can implement the String toString method without using the interface, it's a bit useless, but I have such a task.So I decided to make the method in the interface a little different.But everything stopped working. That is, information has stopped being output to the console.But I can't figure out why.Again, this is my task to do this way. I know I can use the first version, but I'd like to know why the second one doesn't work.

```
public interface Picture {
    public void Draw();
}

class PolyLine extends Line implements Picture{
    int numSides =0;
    Line sideLengths[];
    public PolyLine(Line[] l1) {
        super(l1);
        sideLengths = l1;
        numSides = l1.length;
        
    }

    @Override
    public void Draw() {
        
        System.out.println(" "+"number of sides "+ numSides + " "+ "coordinates of the beginning and end of the lines that make up the polygon\n"+ Arrays.toString(sideLengths) + " " ) ;
    }
}
```

full code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

abstract class Point {
 Double x;
 Double y;

public Point(double x, double y) {

    this.setX(x);
    this.setY(y);
    }

    public double getX() {
    return x;
    }
    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
        }
    public Point() {
        x=0.0;
        y=0.0;
        
    }
    public String toString() {
        
        return x + " " + y + "\n";
    }
}
class ColoredPoint extends Point{
    public Color color;
    
    public ColoredPoint (double x, double y,Color color) {
    super(x,y); 
    this.color=color;
    }
    public Color getColor() {
    return color;
    }
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public ColoredPoint () {
        x=0.0;
        y=0.0;
        color=Color.getRandomColor();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        
        return"("+ x + " " + y +") "+ " " + color + "\n";
    }
}
class Line extends Point{
    public Point start;
    public Point end;
    public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
        start = p1;
        end = p2;   
    }
    public Line(Line[] l1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public double Length()
    {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((end.x - start.x), 2) + Math.pow((end.y - start.y),2));
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        
        return "start point "+ start + " "+ "end point "+ end + " " + "lenght "+Length() ;
    }
}
class ColoredLine extends Line {
    public Color color;
    public ColoredLine(Point p1, Point p2,Color color ) {
        super(p1, p2);
        this.color=color;
    }
    public Color getColor() {
    return color;
    }
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        
        return "start point "+ start + " "+ "end point "+ end + " " + "lenght "+Length() + " \n line color "+color ;
    }
    
}
class PolyLine extends Line implements Picture{
    int numSides =0;
    Line sideLengths[];
    public PolyLine(Line[] l1) {
        super(l1);
        sideLengths = l1;
        numSides = l1.length;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void Draw() {
        
        System.out.println(" "+"number of sides "+ numSides + " "+ "coordinates of the beginning and end of the lines that make up the polygon\n"+ Arrays.toString(sideLengths) + " " ) ;
    }
}
public class FourthLab {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ColoredPoint A = new ColoredPoint(3.5,4.0, Color.Blue);
        System.out.println("A = " + A.toString());
        ColoredPoint B = new ColoredPoint();
        System.out.println("B = " + B.toString());
        ColoredPoint C = new ColoredPoint(0.0,4.0, Color.Orange);
        System.out.println("C = " + C.toString());
        Line L1 = new Line (A,B);
        Line L2 = new Line (B,C);
        Line L3 = new Line (C,A);
        System.out.println("L1 = \n" + L1.toString());
        Line Colored_L1 = new ColoredLine (A,B,Color.getRandomColor());
        System.out.println("L1_colored = \n" + Colored_L1.toString());
        Line[] l1 = {L1,L2,L3};
        PolyLine Triangle = new  PolyLine (l1) ;
        System.out.println("Triangle = \n" + Triangle.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: An interface with a `public String toString();` is useless/pointless, because since the `Object` class has that method, *every* object has that method.

Comment: @Abra The IDE issues a warning : `the operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String, void`

Comment: You need to call `Draw()` somewhere, to print the output.  But don't try to do it within the `System.out.println` argument, as someone else suggested; because you've given `Draw` a `System.out.println` of its own.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem where exactly should I call `Draw()`? For me, this method is defined only for one class..I'm completely confused... :(

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem even if I call it, I have to conditionally assign it to some variable. But I do not know which variable can be passed void format.

Comment: The whole point  of a `void` method is that you do NOT assign it to some variable.  There's nothing for you to assign.

Answer (score -1):

The output you are seeing fro the first version has nothing whatsoever to do with the `Picture` interface. You are seeing it because you are printing the instance to STDOUT, with something like:

```
System.out.println(myObj);
```

which in turn uses the `toString()` method, which you overrode.

Try:

```
Systenm.out.println(myObj.Draw());
```

---

An interface with a `public String toString();` is useless/pointless, because since the `Object` class has that method, every object has that method.

Comment: Interface `java.util.Comparator` has method [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) Is that also useless/pointless since the `Object` class has that method?

Comment: @Bohemian yeah, i know it about String toString. I just wrote it in my question that it is useless to implement the interface in this way.But I didn't understand where I should get `myObj `from because I haven't created any objects there yet.

Comment: @Bohemian I would like to have some void type method in the interface.To redefine it later in some classes.What exactly am I doing wrong here `System.out.println ()`?

Comment: @abra It is not useless, but exists only to provide its special contract via Java doc, which says it defines `equals()` to `true` if the other object is “a comparator that imposes the same ordering”. IMHO, if it changed the meaning, it should not override and should be a different method, perhaps `hasSameOrdering()` etc. Java has many poorly designed ideas, classes and method names.